# a veces ingresa datos y otras no. Visual studio CRUD

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, visual-studio, wpf, crud

Tengo que entregar un proyecto con método crud y conexión a base de datos. El problema es que cuando intento unas el método **create** a veces ingresa los datos y otras no (la mayoría de las veces no), solo me entrega el mensaje flash en los errores , no entiendo que podría ser, la conexion a la base de datos esta bien ya que si puedo usar los metodos **read**, **update** y **delete**. Casi se me olvida la interfaz esta siendo trabajada en WFP.

**Metodo create**

```
        {
            try
            {
                Datos.Libro liib = new Datos.Libro()
                {
                    CodLib = this.Codlib,
                    NombreLib = this.Nomlib,
                    CodISBN = this.Isbn,
                    Autor = this.Autor,
                    Fechapublic = this.Fechapublic,
                    Editorial = this.Editorial,
                    Categoria = Categoria.ToString(),
                    Genero = Genero.ToString()

                };
                Conexion.Bli.Libro.Add(liib);
                Conexion.Bli.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: Deberias agregar el error que te tira, pero si aveces te agrega y otras no, podria ser un problema de primary key, que intentas agregar siempre el mismo registro. Pero agrega el error para saber que te dice. y en el Catch coloca para tomar la excepcion.

Comment: Ahi agregue esa parte.

Comment: Cuando ejecutas, pone un punto de interrupcion en los catch y fijate si entran ahi y coloca el error que te lanza.

Comment: ese es el botón ingresar, es mu largo para ponerlo arriba (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1F6hOLaskR7aso87SN9vov-IZcLLiojn3D-yefytxjik/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: No necesito que pongas el código, porque tu problema es que a veces ingresa a base de datos a veces no. Lo que deberias hacer es ejecutar tu aplicacion y fijate en el catch que retornas false, si esta entrando ahi, despues fijarte de no ingresar una primary key duplicada y si no es asi. Que no estes queriendo usar una foreign key que no exista en tu base de datos.

Comment: Mirando tu codigo, no deberias usar un try catch por cada componente, deberias manejar esos errores de otra forma, podes manejar mas simple ese metodo

Comment: Podria ser cosa de FK, en la base de datos me sale null en la fk de los libros

Comment: los try y catch son para que entregue el mensaje apropiado para cada casilla

Comment: agregue una foto de la tabla en sql, en el link de arriba